# Chained references in python type annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting, higher-kinded-types

Say I have a function that takes a value and a arbitrary number of functions, let's call the function for chain_call.

Without types a simple naive implementation would be:

```
def chain_call(input_value, *args):
    for function in args:
        input_value = function(input_value)
    return input_value
```

As you imagine, input_value could be anything really but it's always the same as the first and only required argument of the first `Callable` in `*args: List[Callable]`.

From here and forward the `Callable`´s  first and only required argument is the same type as the previous items return-type.

So far I've managed to define a quite generic type but it's too loose.

```
def chain_call(input_value: Any, *args: List[Callable[Any], Any]) -> Any: ...
```

What I'd really like is something like

```
T = TypeVar('T')

def chain_call(input_value: T, *args: List[Callable[T, ...], tr]) -> tr: ...
```

Where `T` for `Callable n+1` is `tr` of `Callable n` and the final return-type is tr of `Callable n_max`. I'm not sure how to express this with the type system and would love any guidance.

Comment: I don't thing this is possible in the current `typing` system. Post a feature request on the github sites. (`mypy` and/or `typing`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fully typed function exists in `dry-python/returns`.

We call it `flow`:

```py
from returns.pipeline import flow

assert flow('1', int, float, str) == '1.0'
```

The thing is that `flow` is fully typed via a custom `mypy` plugin we ship with our library. So, it will catch this error case (and [many others](https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/master/typesafety/test_pipeline/test_flow/test_flow_errors.yml)):

```py
from returns.pipeline import flow

def convert(arg: str) -> float:
    ...

flow('1', int, convert)
# error: Argument 1 to "convert" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

Docs: https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pipeline.html

Source: https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/0f7d02d0c491a7c65c74e6c0645f12fccc53fe18/returns/_internal/pipeline/flow.py

Plugin: https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/0f7d02d0c491a7c65c74e6c0645f12fccc53fe18/returns/contrib/mypy/_features/flow.py

Comment: Wow awesome to see you posting an answer to my old question, I had forgotten about this. But I do use your library (and other dry-python) for these kind of things. Keep the great work up!  Would love to chat with you sometime :)

Comment: Awesome! We have a chat: https://t.me/drypython Join us!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is currently not something that's possible to type using PEP 484 type hints.

The best you can do is use overloads to approximate a signature: basically, we hard-code what the signature ought to be up to a certain number then fall back to inferring 'Any':

```
from typing import TypeVar, overload, Any, Callable

T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')
T3 = TypeVar('T3')
T4 = TypeVar('T4')

@overload
def chain_call(input_value: T1, 
               *f_rest: Callable[[T1], T1]) -> T1: ...
@overload
def chain_call(input_value: T1, 
               f1: Callable[[T1], T2],
               f2: Callable[[T2], T3],
               f3: Callable[[T3], T4],
               f4: Callable[[T4], Any],
               *f_rest: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Any: ...
@overload
def chain_call(input_value: T1, 
               f1: Callable[[T1], T2],
               f2: Callable[[T2], T3],
               f3: Callable[[T3], T4]) -> T4: ...
@overload
def chain_call(input_value: T1, 
               f1: Callable[[T1], T2],
               f2: Callable[[T2], T3]) -> T3: ...
@overload
def chain_call(input_value: T1, 
               f1: Callable[[T1], T2]) -> T2: ...
def chain_call(input_value, *f_rest):
    for function in f_rest:
        input_value = function(input_value)
    return input_value
```

Here, I hard-coded what ought to happen up to 3 input functions (and started with an overload for the special case where all the callables happen to have the same input and output type).

This technique is how typeshed currently types things like the `zip` function, which can accept an arbitrary number of iterables.

Note: you may need to use the latest version of mypy from master for this code to work verbatim.

Comment: Thank you, I was suspecting that I’d have to resort to something like this but was hoping someone had a better solution.

Comment: Michael0x2a: Your answer is still great for those who want to use vanilla python and mypy. But changed the accepted answer since sobolevn actually solves the underlying problem, so future searchers can see that solution which is a bit less convoluted to use.